# How Vector.remove(Object e) works in Java?

Tags: java, vector

I'd like to know how the method `remove(Object e)` works. I have this code:

```
    Vector<Actor> toChoose;
    Vector<Actor> toDelete;

    toDelete = film.getActors();
    toChoose = db.getActors();

    System.out.println("To Delete:");
    for (int i = 0; i < toDelete.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(toDelete.get(i).getName());
    }
    System.out.println("===============");

    System.out.println("To choose:");
    for (int i = 0; i < toChoose.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(toChoose.get(i).getName());
    }
    System.out.println("===============");


    for (int i = 0; i < selectedActors.size(); i++){
        toChoose.remove((Actor) selectedActors.get(i));
    }

    System.out.println("To choose after deleting:");
    for (int i = 0; i < toChoose.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(toChoose.get(i));
    }
    System.out.println("===============");
```

And this is the output:

```
To Delete:
Angelina Jolie
Louis de Funes
===============
To choose:
Angelina Jolie
Louis de Funes
Lukáš Hamrla
Brad Pitt
===============
To choose after deleting:
Angelina Jolie
Louis de Funes
Lukáš Hamrla
Brad Pitt
===============
```

I think it's obviously what I want. I don't know how objects from `toDelete` won't delete in `toChoose`.

Comment: How about `removeAll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector` implements `List`. And in order to remove from a list, the javadoc says:

> removes the element with the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))) (if such an element exists).

As no elements were removed, it certainly means `Actor` does not implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`.

Notes:

- use a `List` next time, such as an `ArrayList`; `Vector` has been obsolete for many, many years (but for some reason it *still* is not marked as deprecated!!!);
- `List` has `.{remove,add}All()`;
- foreach loops have existed for many, many years.

So, to modernize your code: declare

```
List<Actor> toChoose = ...;
// etc
```

Also:

```
for (final Actor actor: toChoose)
    System.out.println(actor);
```

And finally:

```
toChoose.removeAll(selectedActors);
```

Comment: About the foreach loops, consider we also see some casting in there and the question being asked, I think you need to give the OP some time to learn a bit more and he'll get there. Everything in its own time. (but... yeah)

Comment: Also, the OP is calling remove with actors from `selectedActors` which is never declared.

Comment: @Aurand: yeah I saw that, but I assumed that was just a bad case of failing to supply the correct code (and hoped it wasn't the actual problem).

Comment: @LukasHamrla: then you should accept fge's answer by clicking on the "tick" symbol on the left of his answer.

Comment: Aurand: yes, ive forgotten written it here, but it is there. Problem was i havent implement equals()

Comment: @haylem: i'm trying, but i have to wait 2 more minutes, dont worry :)

Comment: @LukasHamrla see edit, it contains hints to bring your code up to the 21st century :p

Comment: @fge: that's not fair, Java 5 (back then 1.5) was introduced in 2004, so we already had crap code in the early 21st century :)

Comment: @LukasHamrla if you implement `.equals()`, you MUST also implement `.hashCode()`. That is the [most fundamental contract of Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Actor actor : toDelete){
        toChoose.remove(actor);
}
```

As has been mentioned by others.  This will probably not do what you expect if `Actor` does not implement `.equals` and `.hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

I'll go on a limb: `Actor` needs to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`, but doesn't.